# Linq To Entities - how to filter on child entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

I have entities `Group` and `User`.
the `Group` entity has `Users` property which is a list of Users.
User has a property named `IsEnabled`.

I want to write a linq query that returns a list of `Group`s, which only consists of `User`s whose `IsEnabled` is true.

so for example, for data like below 
`AllGroups`
**Group A** 
User 1 (IsEnabled = true) 
User 2 (IsEnabled = true) 
User 3 (IsEnabled = false)

**Group B** 
User 4 (IsEnabled = true) 
User 5 (IsEnabled = false) 
User 6 (IsEnabled = false)

I want to get
`FilteredGroups`
**Group A** 
User 1 (IsEnabled = true) 
User 2 (IsEnabled = true)

**Group B** 
User 4 (IsEnabled = true)

I tried the following query, but Visual Studio tells me that 
[Property or indexer 'Users' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only]

```
FilteredGroups = AllGroups.Select(g => new Group()
                    {
                        ID = g.ID,
                        Name = g.Name,
                        ...
                        Users = g.Users.Where(u => u.IsInactive == false)
                    });
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: are you using EF4? If so, are you using POCO's? How is `Group.Users` declared?

Comment: You could achieve this easily with filtered Include. Vote for the feature [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to do this by turning the query upside down:

```
var users = (from user in Users.Include("Group")
             where user.IsEnabled
             select user).ToList().AsQueryable()

from (user in users
      select user.Group).Distinct()
```

By using the ToList() you force a roundtrip to the database which is required because otherwise the deferred execution comes in the way. The second query only re-orders the retrieved data.

<s>Note: You might not be able to udpate your entities afterwards!</s>

Comment: can you help me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120664/how-to-group-by-on-2-child-entities-and-get-total-of-both-this-child-entities

Answer (score 17):

There is no "nice" way of doing this, but you could try this - project both, `Group` and filtered `Users` onto an anonymous object, and then `Select` just the `Groups`:

```
var resultObjectList = AllGroups.
                       Select(g => new
                               {
                                   GroupItem = g,
                                   UserItems = g.Users.Where(u => !u.IsInactive)
                               }).ToList();

FilteredGroups = resultObjectList.Select(i => i.GroupItem).ToList();
```

This isn't a documented feature and has to do with the way EF constructs SQL queries - in this case it should filter out the child collection, so your `FilteredGroups` list will only contain active users.

If this works, you can try merging the code:

```
FilteredGroups = AllGroups.
                 Select(g => new
                               {
                                   GroupItem = g,
                                   UserItems = g.Users.Where(u => !u.IsInactive)
                               }).
                 Select(r => r.GroupItem).
                 ToList();
```

(This is untested and the outcome depends on how EF will process the second `Select`, so it would be nice if you let us know which method works after you've tried it).

Comment: The second Select doesn't appear to do what is intended and filter the UserItems on the GroupItem itself, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

try something like this and you'll still have your entities:

```
FilteredGroups = AllGroups.Select(g => new
{
    Group = g,
    Users = g.Users.Where(u => u.IsInactive == false)
}).AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.Group);
```

That way you should still be able to use `Group.Users`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your entity structure, try this:

```
var userGroups = context.Users.Where(u => !u.IsInactive).GroupBy(u => u.Group);

foreach (var userGroup in userGroups)
{
    // Do group stuff, e.g.:
    foreach (var user in userGroup)
    {
    }
}
```

And you certainly can modify your entities!

Answer (score 0):

Use inner linq query

```
var FilteredGroups = (from g in AllGroups
                      select new Group()
                        {
                            ID = g.ID,
                            Name = g.Name,
                            ...
                            Users = (from user in g.Users
                                     where user.IsInactive == false
                                     select user).ToList()
                        });
```