# LINQ Query - how sort and filter on eager fetch

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

How do I do a eager query of a parent child relationship that:

1. filters a on child  fields
2. sorts on both parent and child
3. return a List or Parents with the children pre-populated

If I try

```
from p in _context.Parents.Include("children")
join c in _context.childrenon p.Id equals c.ParentId 
where d.DeletedDate == null
orderby p.Name ascending, c.Name 
select p
```

Then I get the Parent object back but each Parent has NULL for children

if I try

```
from p in _context.Parents.Include("children")
orderby p.Name ascending
select p
```

The query returns all Parents and children but they are not filtered or sorted.

The result I want back is a `IEnumerable<Parent>`
i.e.

```
Parent[0].name = "foo"
Parent[0].children = IEnumerable<Child>
Parent[1].name = "bar"
Parent[1].children = IEnumerable<Child>
```

Comment: I assume each parent may have zero or more children.  What's the expected output when a parent has multiple children?

Comment: @tvanfosson I have updated my question with this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

The first query gives the impression that you want to "flatten out" the results in objects, like this (pseudocode, I hope it's clear what I mean):

```
{ Parent1, Child1 }
{ Parent1, Child2 }
{ Parent1, Child3 }
{ Parent2, Child1 }
```

In this case each result "row" would be an object having a `Parent` and a `Child` property, and you could sort by parent name and then by child name.

The second query just returns the `Parent` objects and (you don't show it but I assume EF has been instructed to do that) each one has a `Children` collection. In this case you can only sort by parent name; if you want to sort each `Parent`'s children, sort the `Children` collection on that object by itself.

Which of the two do you want to do?

**Update**

OK, it seems you want the second one. I don't believe it can be done directly. You can just do it when you enumerate the results - since the `Parent`s are already sorted, simply sort each one's children:

```
var sortedChildren = parent.Children.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: I would prefer the 2nd option.  My end goal is for a select box that is grouped with optGroup tags

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but are you suggesting fetching the Parents  from the database and then doing the sorting in memory?

Comment: I got it working with the Selecting ALL data then sorting in memory. Yes this is probably not the most efficent, but My data set is only small and it is easy to code p.Chilren.Where(x => x.DeletedDate == null).OrderBy(x => x.Name); with in a loop of each parent

Comment: @Daveo - Yes, it probably won't matter much if you don't have large data amounts, but in case you want ordering at the database level, feel free to use the workaround in my answer.

Comment: @Yakimych: Does making the projection to an anonymous type and ordering inside the query make EF translate it to SQL somehow? If it does then I 'd be very interested in learning that. If it doesn't then the sort will be done in memory anyway.

Comment: @Jon - Yes, it does. In fact, it's a workaround used for such cases, but basically when you select the parents and the children (ordered and filtered), EF constructs the query exactly the way you want it. It's just that you can't achieve this by cleaner C# code (`Include` will not allow you to order the child collections, so you do the whole thing via projections). Note that I don't use `Include` at all, and yet the `Parents` in the resulting collection have the `Children` collections loaded. You can also verify the EF queries by running them through the SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 10):

There is no direct way of doing this, but you can use somewhat of a workaround - project the parent and children onto an annonymous object and then select and return the parent from the object.

See similar question: [Linq To Entities - how to filter on child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720573/linq-to-entities-how-to-filter-on-child-entities/4724297#4724297)

In your case you will have something along the lines of:

```
var resultObjectList = _context.
                       Parents.
                       Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null).
                       OrderBy(p => p.Name).
                       Select(p => new
                                 {
                                     ParentItem = p,
                                     ChildItems = p.Children.OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                                 }).ToList();

List<Parent> resultingCollection = resultObjectList.Select(o => o.ParentItem).ToList();
```

Comment: I am trying this way now, when it produces the correct SQL but the resultingCollection does not have the Child Items filled. Is thre anyway to CAST back from the anonymous type back to a Parent Object with the Children List ? Or should I just just make a new View model that matches the anon type (I am using mvc .net)

Comment: @Daveo It's a bit manual but what you can do is just select into a new ParentItem object and map all the fields individually, and when you map the ChildItems list, do something like ChildItems = new List<ChildItem> { p.ChildItems.Where(c => c.DeletedDate == null) }

Bit of a late reply but hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

prefetching child fields:

```
using (BlogDataContext context = new BlogDataContext())
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Blog>(c => c.Categories);
    options.LoadWith<Blog>(c => c.Title);
    context.LoadOptions = options;
    Blog blog = context.Blogs.Single<Blog>(c => c.BlogId == 1);
}
```

Comment: I think LoadOptions only works with DataContext, not Entity.DbContext