# Entity Code First DbSet using include with conditions

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, entity

I have a class that calls ICB that has a property of type list of ICBResource, that is possible to associate many Resources to one ICB, the problem is when I want to delete a Resource associated with ICB that is not truly deleted and only set true in an deleted boolean property, the resources deleted still return from DB.

**Example:**

**If this ICB has 10 resources associated but later 3 of resources were deleted, I want to list only the 7 remaining.**

There is a way to implement a conditional for the .includes ?

```
// ICB class
public class ICB
{

    public ICB()
    {
        ICBResources = new List<ICBResource>();
    }

    public int ICBId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ICBResource> ICBResources { get; set; }

}

// Resource class
public class ICBResource
{
    public int ICBResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICB ICB { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

}



//here is my Repository and how I select my ICB with the resources associated
public ICB GetICB(int id)
{
    return GetDbSet<ICB>()
            .Include("ICBResources")
            .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ICBId == id);

}
```

There is a way to include another conditional like a Where(i => i.ICBResources.Where(r=> !r.deleted);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter nested collection Entity Framework objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects)

Comment: @Edin, this link does work for Code First.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
public ICB GetICB(int id)
{
    return GetDbSet<ICB>()
        .Include("ICBResources")
        .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ICBId == id && i.ICBResources.Where(r => !r.Deleted).Count() == 0);

}
```

If the question is about filtering related, the answer is no.

Comment: It seems that will limite my query in return the ICB only if has no Resource deleted. I just want to return the resources that wasn't deleted, not compromise tehe return of my main object ICB.