# Filter on collection inside collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have some classes modeling a guest user account and among others the guest's state and the guest's host:

```
public class GuestUser
{
    public string LoginID {get; set;}

    public List<GuestDetails> GuestDetailsList {get; set;}
}

public class GuestDetails
{
    public GuestGroupUserState State {get; set;}

    public GuestCreator GuestCreator {get; set;}
    public GuestUser GuestUser {get; set;}
}

public class GuestCreator
{
    public string CreatorLoginID {get; set;}

    public List<GuestDetails> GuestDetailsList {get; set;}
}

public enum GuestGroupUserState 
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Locked = Active << 1,
    Deleted = Locked << 1
}
```

I want to find all `GuestUsers` and the respective `GuestDetails` for a given `GuestCreator gc` that are not in `Deleted`-State.

So far, I tried

```
var guestUsers = gc.GuestDetailsList
    .Where(gd => gd.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted)
    .Select(gd => gd.GuestUser);
```

but this obviously gives me all the `GuestDetails` for the users, also the ones in `Deleted` state.

Next, I tried with

```
var guestUsers = userRepo.GuestUsers
    .Where(gu => gu.GuestDetails
        .Any(gd => gd.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted && gd.GuestCreator.Equals(gc)));
```

but again this gives me all `GuestDetails` for these users, including the ones in `Deleted`-state.

Is there a way to get all `GuestUser`s that have a `GuestDetail` in non-deleted state and for these users, get only the non-deleted `GuestDetail`s? If a `GuestUser` has only deleted details, it shouldn't appear in the list at all. At the moment, I'm `foreach()`ing through my user lists generated with the code snippets above and removing the mismatched details entries from each guest - not the most efficient way I think.

Comment: Are all the `GuestDetailsList` properties populated?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework, or are you filtering in memory?

Comment: @IainGalloway Atm, this is in memory. In the future, I'll query against a database using EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "isn't possible" in a strict sense. You can't "filter" the child collections; you need to allocate new ones:-

```
var guestUsers = ...; // Wherever they're coming from
var filteredUsers = guestUsers
        .Where(x => x.GuestDetails.Any(y => y.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted))
        .Select(x => new GuestUser()
                {
                  LoginId == x.LoginId,
                  GuestDetails == x.GuestDetails
                                   .Where(y => y.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted)
                                   .ToList()
                });
```

Or you might instead want to add a property to your `GuestUser` object:-

```
public List<GuestDetails> ActiveGuestDetailsList
{
  get { return this.GuestDetailsList.Where(y => y.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted); }
}
```

If you're using EF or similar you'll want to perform the filtering on the database and project onto a DTO instead.

Comment: How did you compare `y.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted` . I've just tried and it says that it doesn't implement operator ==

Comment: What do you mean by "perform the filtering on the database"?

Comment: The OP performs the comparison `gd.State != GuestUserState.Deleted` in his example code. I assume that either it's a typo, or there's an implicit conversion.

Comment: It's a typo... Should be `GuestGroupUserState` everywhere, I'll fix it in the post.

Comment: @Thaoden: I mean, if the records are coming from the database then you don't want to pull all the records into memory and then filter them in memory. You want to perform the query *on the database*.

Comment: @IainGalloway Well, that's what Linq is for, I thought? `dbContext.GuestUsers.Select(...)` should retrieve only the items I asked for and not perform the filtering in memory. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Untill you say `ToList()`, the collection is still `IQueryable` which is a bit faster.

Comment: Well, first of all, if you're using `new` inside your query, you won't be able to [track changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456848%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) because the objects you have in memory are a projection rather than an attached entity.

Comment: More importantly, if you're performing this kind of query with *any* O/RM you need to be acutely aware of the [N+1 selects problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) (which my second example would trigger).

Comment: If you can't afford to use a projection, you'll need to use something like https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters

Comment: related:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects

Comment: Is there a way in this solution to avoid having guests with empty `GuestDetails`? Something better than a `Where(gu => gu.GuestDetails.Count() != 0)`?

Comment: So if I got it right, assuming I don't worry wether these entities are attached to the context or not, possibly using `AsNoTracking`, I can safely use your code snippet without blowing up my database or the access times to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77114/discussion-between-iain-galloway-and-thaoden).

Answer (score 1):

With your current model architecture, you can't get rid of `GuestUser`'s deleted `GuestDetails` on the `GuestDetailsList`. To achieve your goal, you'll need to change the

`public List<GuestDetails> GuestDetailsList {get; set;}`

to:

`public GuestDetails GuestDetails {get; set;}`

on your GuestUser class. With a one-to-one relationship between `GuestUser` and `GuestDetails` you won't have such problems and will be able to get the correct information via:

```
var guestUsers = gc.GuestDetailsList
    .Where(g => g.State != GuestGroupUserState.Deleted)
    .Select(g => g.GuestUser);
```

Comment: That gives me all `GuestUser`s that have a non-deleted state, along with all their `GuestDetail`s - even the deleted ones.

Comment: I've edited it with a more appropriated answer.
If you really need to stick with the one-to-many relationship between `GuestUser` and `GuestDetails`, then you should go with Iain Galloway's answer.

Comment: Yes, the one-to-many is a requirement, I didn't like it when it came up :/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you please elucidate why you need the one-to-many relationship? Maybe we can find a work-around on that.

Comment: It has to be possible that a single `GuestUser` can be in more than one group. I left the groups out for brevity, but in addition to the creator, the `GuestDetail` has a reference to the group.