# Filter the “Includes” table on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, filter, include

i want to join two tables with entity framework extension method. i want to get 
albums from MusicAlbums table and get musics from PlayLists.

my Code :

```
var result = db.MusicAlbums.Include(p => p.PlayLists)
    .Where(p => p.userID == uID && p.aktifMi == true).ToList();
```

I can get  all musics and albums but i must filter and i must get only active musics from playlists table.

like this:

```
var result = db.MusicAlbums.Include(p => p.PlayLists.aktifMi=true)
    .Where(p => p.userID == uID && p.aktifMi == true).ToList();
```

how to I can write query? my active column name "aktifMi".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter nested collection Entity Framework objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects)

Comment: but not working this example :/

Comment: Yeah, because the accepted answer is "It isn't possible to filter nested collection"