# Is it better additional query or get all data and filter in the client?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a query with EF Core in which I would like to include a property and from this property, that it is a ICollection, I would like filter what data to get.

It is something like that:

```
myDbContext.MyEntity.Where(x => x.ID == 1).Include(x => x.MyCollection.Where(y => y.isEnabled == true));
```

However, I get an error because it is not possible to filter the included properties.

In fact, the items in the collection will be few, about 6 or 7, so I was thinking that I could include all and later filter the data in the client.

Another option it would be get the the main entity first and in a second query to get the childs that really I need.

I always read that the connections to the database are expensive, so it is better to do as less queries as possible, but also I read that the best practice it is to get only the data that I need and no filter in the client, but it is better filter in the query.

But in this case, with EF Core, it seems that I can't filter in the query, so I would like to know what is better, 2 queries and get only the data that I need or one query getting all the data and filter later in the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: Where is your bottleneck? Serverside, clientside or network traffic?

Comment: @mjwills this would seem to be more of a question about a consequence of how the top answer to that question says isn't possible, so it's related but not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in this case, with EF Core, it seems that I can't filter in the query, so I would like to know what is better, 2 queries and get only the data that I need or one query getting all the data and filter later in the client.

Which is longer? One long piece of string, or two shorter pieces of string?

You don't know, because I haven't told you the actual lengths. You don't know if it's a 1m string versus two 5cm strings or a 10cm string vs two 8cm string.

And your question here is the same. It's better to do fewer queries than many, and it's better to do short queries than long queries. When a choice is on only one of those metrics (e.g. the shorter query from doing a simple `Where` on the database vs a simple `Where` in memory on all results) then we can make sound *a priori* judgements about which is likely to be the more efficient, and choose accordingly.

When though we have competing factors in play we have to:

1. Decide whether we even care: If they're going to still be pretty fast either way it might not be worth worrying about; find bigger fish to fry.
2. Measure.
3. Make sure what we are measuring is realistic.

The third point is important as one can often create data sets that would make one come out the victor, and other data sets that would make the other win. We need to make sure we're correctly modelling what is encountered in real life.

When the difference is small, or if they are both fast either way (and/or the use is so rare that it's still not a big deal), then just go for whichever is easier to code and maintain.