# EF core Access list through Include

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Model named as **Blog**:

```
public class Blog
    {
        [Key]
        public int blogId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string blogTitle { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.Html)]
        public string blogDescription { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime blogDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isPublished { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BlogCategory blogCategory { get; set; }
        public List<Comments> blogComments { get; set; }
    }
```

And another model **Comment**:

```
public class Comments
    {
        [Key]
        public int authorId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string commentAuthor { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime commentDate { get; set; }
        public bool isHidden { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string commentAuthorEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string commentDescription { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

In the blogs controller I want to access all the comments where `isHidden = false`

What I have tried is:

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
           .Include(cat => cat.blogCategory)
           .Include(comments => comments.blogComments.Any(c => !c.isHidden))
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.blogId == id);
```

But all I am getting exception is

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'comments => comments.blogComments.Find(c => Not(c.isHidden))' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to filter when using include (yet). See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833) for details. An alternative is to use global filters, but it might have other repercussions in your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF: Include with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

Comment: @GertArnold I don't think that this is a possible duplicate. I would like to request you to look over this question again. If possible, Please help.

Comment: Not a duplicate? What else are you asking than how to do filtered Include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not do filter in `Include` in EF core, try to use below code instead

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
       .Include(cat => cat.blogCategory)
       .Include(comments => comments.blogComments)
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.blogId == id);

blog.blogComments = blog.blogComments.Where(b => b.isHidden == false).ToList();
```

Refer to [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Answer (score 0):

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
       .Include(cat => cat.blogCategory)
       .Include(comments => comments.blogComments)
       .Select(x=> {
            x.blogCategory = x.blogCategory;
            x.blogComments = x.blogComments.Where(y=>!y.IsHidden)
       })
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.blogId == id);
```

Since it's a IQueryable this will  have the same result. It will only return the comments where the blog comments are hidden. This is considering that you want to return all the blogs and not just the blogs whose comments are hidden.

Comment: This doesn't return a `Blog` though.

Comment: The trick here is tje select statement. You can return anything you want with it. For  example new Blog(){ mpla mpla}

Answer (score 0):

You must use entity framework projections.

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
.Select(p => new Blog
{
    blogComments  = p.blogComments.Where(s => !s.isHidden )
}.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.blogId == id);
```

Comment: "must" is a bit strong

Comment: afaik there is no other way. look please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core

Answer (score -1):

bool value is true of false so try:
//untested

```
(comments => comments.blogComments.where(c=>c.isHidden==false))
```