# Entity Framework Core 3.0 new features - filtered include

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following this problem with filtering Include in EF Core:

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

is this something that will be possible in EF 3.0?

Comment: You can trace the feature request on [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833)

Comment: The referred question now serves as duplicate, [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618096/861716). As explained there, filtered include is supported as off EF core 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible, [using .Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include):

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(e => e.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("Cheese")))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, EF Core doesn't support to filter in the `Include` method.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows easily filter included entities.

The `ThenInclude` is not yet supported but you just have to include the last filter to have the same behavior.

Example:

```
_dbContext.User
    .IncludeFilter(x=>x.UserRoles)
    .IncludeFilter(x=>x.UserRoles.SelectMany(y => y.Roles.Where(z => z.Active)))
```