# Conditional navigation properties in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a User table with a corresponding UserAudits table that tracks the changes. The operation type is stored in the audit table (insert, update, delete).

I want to create a navigation property on my User entity so I can fetch the "Inserted" record from the audit table. Is this possible? Usually when setting up a navigation property there is no way to specify extra conditions on the join.

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public UserAudit InsertedAuditRecord {get; set;} // <-- How to configure this?
}
```

UserAudit:

```
public class UserAudit
{
    public int AuditId {get; set;
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string OperationType {get; set;}
}
```

I know I could create a one-to-many navigation property on my User entity and then query that:

```
ICollection<UserAudit> UserAudits {get; set;}
UserAudit InsertedAuditRecord => UserAudits.First(ua => ua.OperationType = "insert");
```

But this would require bringing the entire audit table for the user into memory just to find a single record.

Surely there's some way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which EF core version?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm currently on 2.2.2 but can upgrade to 3 if necessary as my application is still in development.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for (which is `Include()` using `Where()` clause in it), is now added to `.net 5`. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/862795) answer.

Answer (score -1):

A `Where` (`First`) on the child record does not bring the whole child object back.

Comment: Please can you elaborate?

Comment: What's your sql when you do the query?

Comment: If i'm using an `ICollection<UserAudit>` it is null unless I call `Include(u => u.UserAudits)` which brings back all records.