# Exclude deleted child when using EF core Include

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my entity structure:

[image]
My code to get the **Courses** with all child **Tests**:

```
var course = await Db.Courses.Include(x => x.Tests).FirstOrDefaultAsync(y => y.CourseId == id);
```

It includes all the child **Tests** related to the **Courses**. But I want to include all Tests that status is not deleted (`IsDeleted = false`). To do that I have use this code:

```
var course = await Db.Courses.Include(x => x.Tests.Where(y=>!y.IsDeleted)).FirstOrDefaultAsync(y => y.CourseId == id);
```

But it doesn't exclude the deleted Tests. Can anybody tell me how I can exclude the deleted tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my solution. I solved it by adding a global filter like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Test>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Details explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Comment: But what if you want all records including those having IsDeleted = true? As per docs you linked, in such case you need to use `IgnoreQueryFilters()`. You should mark your own answer as accepted! +1

Answer (score 0):

Regular include cannot work with filter. You need to download Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore from nuget. And use code below

```
var course = await Db.Courses.Where(y => y.CourseId == id).IncludeFilter(x => x.Tests.Where(y => y.IsDeleted == false)).FirstOrDefaultAsync;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not do filter in Include in EF core, try to use below code instead

```
var course = await Db.Courses.Include(x => x.Tests).FirstOrDefaultAsync(y => y.CourseId == id);
course.Tests = course.Tests.Where(t => !t.IsDeleted).ToList();
```

Refer to [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: This is a good solution, but it seems a little costly. I have added a solution by exploring documentation.