# EF Core - How to Include child but limit the number of child entities returned

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core 3.1. I have a parent with thousands of child elements, but I only want to retrieve the latest 10 children (and later will use pagination). When I run the following query:

```
context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child)
```

it will return all children and is incredibly slow. How can I return only 10 children and later use it for pagination? EF prevents using lambdas inside the Include, for example `context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child.Take(10))` throws an exception.

Do I need multiple calls to the DB?

Comment: Wait for EF 5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716. Until then: project to a view model.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, I know it's a feature of the upcoming .NET 5. That's why I first said I am using .NET Core 3.1. I don't want to use a .NET 5 preview.

Comment: If the query is limited to parent and children, you could change the subject to the child table, filter by parent ID, include the parent, and limit the children, before switching the relationship back in a projection. The parent should all be to the same reference parent object so any one will do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this query helps.

```
var result = Parentlist
.Select(a => new { a, Childs = a.Childs.Take(10).ToList() })
.AsEnumerable() 
.Select(x =>
{
    x.a.Childs = x.Childs;
    return x.a;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: Interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

```
    var model = context.parent.Where(condition).OrderBy(x).Take(y).Skip(z)
    .select(c=> new parentViewModel 
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name= c.Name,
        children = c.children.where(condition)
                    .OrderByDescending(x=> x.CreateDate)
                    .take(pageSize)
                    .Select(x => new childViewModel {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      ChildName = x.Name
                       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you write the query starting from the children

```
Context.Chidlren.Where(x => condition ( x.Parent)).Include(x => x.Parent).Take(10).Select(x=> x.Parent)
```

Comment: What I understand id that OP wants the first 10 children of each parent. Not just children in pages of 10.

Comment: Mmm you are correct. This will only work if there is only 1 matching parent.