# ef core 5.0 How to Filtered Include

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to use the new function Filtered on Include but I'm not getting it right somehow.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#preview-3

I got a product with categories. I need to filter Products on Category title/name. It's a many to many relations.

The category title should contain "Vlees". But somehow **ALL** 6 products in the database get returned, even with the wrong Category.Title name.

```
var products = await _context.Product
   .Include(c => c.ProductCategories.Where(c => c.Category.Title.Contains(containsTitle)))
   .ThenInclude(c => c.Category)
   .ToListAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But somehow **ALL** 6 products in the database get returned

That's because you're querying `_context.Product`. Filtered `Include` is for filtering child collections, not the main query. Therefore you get all products, but all of these products should only contain categories that pass the filter.

You seem to expect that EF only returns product that have categories containing "Vlees" in their names, but that's not the purpose of filtered `Include`. To achieve that, you have to filter the products themselves:

```
_context.Product
    .Where(p => p.ProductCategories.Any(c => c.Category.Title.Contains(containsTitle)))
```

This can be combined with the filtered `Include`s, but not necessarily. If you don't filter the `Includes` you get products filtered by category name, but containing all categories in their collections.

So filtered `Include` gives you the freedom to filter the query result and child collections separately.

Comment: See also [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716).