# EF Core AutoMapper: Filter nested collection in include not applied

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm using EF Core 5. I want to make a query and use `ProjectTo` for mapping my result. But I need to make a filter in nested collection like this:

```
 var questions = await _context
      .MedicalDatas
      .Include(p => p.MedicalDataItems)
      .Include(p => p.MedicalAnswers.Where(x => x.AppUserId == userId))
      .ProjectTo<MedicalDataDto>(_cp)
      .ToListAsync();
```

The 2 navigation properties are included in destination type but when I check the SQL generated by EF Core, there is no `where` clause and it selects all medical answers from the database.

**BUT** without projecting, it works as expected.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: @Fabio Thanks but i saw it before. Actually using ProjectTo seems reseting filters applied to expression.

Comment: You don't need `Include` with `ProjectTo`. Move your filtering in the mapping.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Problem is the dynamic **userId**

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu What a trick! Please submit the answer if you wish so i can upvote you. That was really helpful. This is almost unique.

Comment: Just imagine how easy it would be without Automapper :)

Comment: @Fabio Yeah i agree for some scenarios. But it is clean for small mappings. You write your mapping logic in the responsible place.

Comment: For example One-to-One mappings(where property types and names are same) are redundant, just use same class as database entity.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need **include** with **projectto**

```
var questions = await _context
      .MedicalDatas
      .Where(p => p.MedicalAnswers.Any(x => x.AppUserId == userId))
      .ProjectTo<MedicalDataDto>(_cp)
      .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the OPs request. 

OP wants all MedicalAnswers WHERE AppUserId == userId
This returns all MedicalDatas that have a least one MedicalAnswers WHERE AppUserId == userId