# How to include with where clause in EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having a problem trying to combine a where clause with an include in EntityFrameworkCore.
This is how the class I am trying to do this for looks:

```
public partial class TEntity
{
    public TEntity()
    {
        TData = new HashSet<TData>();
    }

    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    publis string TypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TData> TData { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am trying to get all entities of a specific type:

```
List<TEntity> entityList = dbContext.TEntity.Include("TData").Where(x => x.Type == typeName).ToList();
```

How can I add a filter to this so the collection of `TData` only contains specific entries based on my filter criteria?

Right now, it always returns all of the `TData` entries for the entity but I need to add a filter so only the entries with a specific date are included. Otherwise, thousands of `TData` entries are returned and the query takes forever to execute which is not acceptable.

Comment: Use this - List<TEntity> entityList = dbContext.TEntity.Include("TData").Where(x => x.TypeName == typeName).ToList();

Comment: @Sergey But how can I filter the TData-entries then? The attribute that I need to filter by belongs to the TData-class.

Comment: Please showTdata class properties then.

Comment: With EF Core 5 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/2703673

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: @Vernou I am stuck on EF Core 3. Are there any prerequisites for updating?

Comment: [Breaking changes in EF Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes)

Comment: @Vernou Are there any tutorials/documentations on how to upgrade? I tried upgrading the NuGet packages to EF Core 5 but it simply isn't possible. After somehow figuring out in which order I need to upgrade everything, it turns out that the Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore provider that I am using does not support version 5 of 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```cs
var entityList = dbContext.TEntity
    .Include(t => t.TData.Where(x => x.Type == typeName))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Replace `Select` with `Where`