# C# Show full model Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

`total = await _context.Inspections.Include(p => p.Measurements.Where(e=> e.MaterialId == idMaterial)).ToListAsync();`

The Inspections table contains a list of the Measurements table.
I want to show the complete inspection with the complete Measurements list in case one of its Measurements meets the requirement that the idMaterial is equal to the one entered by the user.
Thanks

Comment: OK. What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace `Where` by `Any`.

Comment: See the difference between `Include` and filtering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
 total = await _context.Inspections.Include(p => p.Measurements)
               .Where(e => e.MaterialId == idMaterial).ToListAsync();
```