# How to apply thenInclude condition on above relations on .net core ef?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, lambda

I have some category tables with one-many relations.
Lets call the classes A,B, and C, and assume that A can contain many B, B can be related to many C.

and imagine this is the result of

```
select A.id, B.id, C.id, C.type 
from A 
left join B on B.a_id=A.id 
left join C on B.id=C.id
```

| A.id | B.id | C.id | C.type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | f |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | f |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | g |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | g |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | g |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | h |

On ef core, If I execute this Linq Lambda

```
 var items = context.As.AsNoTracking()    // As, Bs, Cs, are the DbContext names and the ICollection's name on the Model definition
               .Include(i => i.Bs)
                 .ThenInclude(j => j.C.Where(k=>k.type=="f"));
return await Task.FromResult(items);
```

I get B{id=2} with empty ICollection Cs.

I was expecting those not to appear, as would happen on an inner join.

is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

---

A visual representation would be the following.
I'm getting

```
As (result set)
|-{ }
|  |-A
|  | |-id=1
|  | |-Bs={ }
|  | |     |-B
|  | |     | |-id=1
|  | |     | |-Cs={ }
|  | |     | |     |-C
|  | |     | |     | |-id=1
|  | |     | |     | |-type="f"
|  | |     | |     |
|  | |     | |     |-C
|  | |     | |     | |-id=2
|  | |     | |     | |-type="f"
|  | |     | |
|  | |     |-B
|  | |     | |-id=2
|  | |     | |-Cs={ }
|  |-A
|  | |-id=2
|  | |-Bs={ }
|  | |     |-B
|  | |     | |-id=3
|  | |     | |-Cs={ }
```

when I just want

```
As (result set)
|-{ }
|  |-A
|  | |-id=1
|  | |-Bs={ }
|  | |     |-B
|  | |     | |-id=1
|  | |     | |-Cs={ }
|  | |     | |     |-C
|  | |     | |     | |-id=1
|  | |     | |     | |-type="f"
|  | |     | |     |
|  | |     | |     |-C
|  | |     | |     | |-id=2
|  | |     | |     | |-type="f"
```

Comment: You need to add corresponding filter in `.Include(i => i.Bs)`.

Comment: Yo could also use a join, if you are familiar with sql syntax:
var result=(from a in As
join b in Bs on a.id equals b.a_id
join c in Cs on b.id equals c.b_id
where c.type=="f"
select new { a_id=a.id b_id=b.id, c_id=c.id })

Comment: @GuruStron but how? Bs doesn't have access to C properties, it has only access to Cs, wich is an ICollection

Comment: @PabloFuenzalida what about `A` with `id == 2`? Should it be present in the result?

Comment: @GuruStron yu are right, I'm fixing it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filtered `Include` only works on the collection itself. A subsequent `ThenInclude` doesn't filter the preceding `Include`. This is what I mean:

```cs
context.As
    .Include(a => a.Bs) // Fully populates A.Bs
    .ThenInclude(b => b.Cs.Where(c => c.type == "f")); // Partly populates B.Cs
```

You expected the filter on `Cs` to filter `Bs` as well, but `Bs` are only affected by a filtered `Include` on `Bs`, which in your case would amount to:

```cs
context.As
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.Cs.Any(c => c.type == "f"))
    .ThenInclude(b => b.Cs.Where(c => c.type == "f"))
```

Comment: More details on scope and effect of filtered `Include`s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716).