# filter child entities while fetching a parent entity EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-5.0

I am using EF Core 3.1.x
I have now updated to EF Core 5.0.8
I have three tables:

- Posts
- PostTags
- Tags

Posts has m-to-m relationship with Tags and the PostTags table holds the data.

While fetching a Post, I also need the tags that are not deleted for that post.

For an example:

A post object can be like this:

```
Id: 1
Title: Harry Potter
Description: Abraca Dabra!
```

And Tags can be like:

```
Id: 1
Name: Fantasy
Id: 2
Name: Sci-fi
Id: 3
Name: Thriller
```

And PostTags for the Post of id-1:

```
Id: 1
PostId: 1
TagId: 1
Deleted: false
Id: 2
PostId: 1
TagId: 2
Deleted: false
Id: 3
PostId: 1
TagId: 3
Deleted: true
```

After executing the query, the result should be:

```
Id: 1
Title: Harry Potter
Description: Abraca Dabra!
Tags: Fantasy, Sci-fi
```

I was trying this query:

```
var result = await _context.Posts
            .Where(x => x.Id == PostId)
            .Include(pt => pt.PostTags.Where(pt => pt.Deleted == false)).ThenInclude(t => t.Tags)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It didn't filter the PostTags which are not deleted.

Comment: Are you using efcore 5? Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: Also consider to use Global Query Filters for filtering soft deleted entities https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: @CaiusJard I am using efcore 3.x the asp.net core version is 3.1.4. I have seen that efcore 5 has integrated this feature

Comment: @momt99 I will have a look at it and try it in my app.

Comment: @GertArnold I have update my code like this: var result =  context.Posts
            .Where(x => x.Id == PostId)
            .Include(pt => pt.PostTags.Where(pt => pt.Deleted == false)).ThenInclude(t => t.Tags)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
I have updated efcore to 5.0.8
But I am still not getting the expected result. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: OK, that's a sensible step! Please [edit] your question with this new information. Then you can also show in more detail what you expected and didn't get.

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you look at the link suggested to you in the first comments? That exactly describes your problem. You have to filter query *and* the Include.

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't quite simple, because posts without tags or with only deleted tags should (I assume) also be listed.
Also, the query must be able to be translated by EF Core. There are differences between the providers, therefore I have avoided to group in LINQ to SQL.
Then the comma separated list of tags has to be generated.

First, we perform a left join operation and load the data:

```cs
var postTags = (from p in db.Posts
                from pt in db.PostTags.Where(pt2 => p.Id == pt2.PostId && pt2.Deleted == false).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Title,
                    p.Description,
                    TagName = pt.Tag.Name ?? string.Empty
                })
                .ToList();
```

This produces the following SQL Statement:

```sql
SELECT p.Id, p.Title, p.Description, COALESCE(t0.Name, '') AS TagName
FROM Posts AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT p0.PostId, p0.TagId
  FROM PostTags AS p0
  WHERE NOT (p0.Deleted)
) AS t ON p.Id = t.PostId
LEFT JOIN Tags AS t0 ON t.TagId = t0.Id
```

To create the comma separated list we need some processing with LINQ to objects in memory:

```cs
var result = postTags.GroupBy(pt => new { pt.Id, pt.Title, pt.Description })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        g.Key.Title,
        g.Key.Description,
        Tags = string.Join(", ", g.Select(pt => pt.TagName))
    })
    .ToList();
```