# EF Linq include last

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-6.0

I have 2 tables one with cities and another with temperature/date values for the cities, a city can have multiple dates with temperature.

how could I by EF + linq bring the cities + the most recent temperature of each one

something like: `_context.city.include(x=> x.temperature().last());`

Comment: Please always use a tag indicating the exact EF version because that's very important for how a question can be answered.

Comment: oka, good advice, I'm using EFC 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always should take control over which temperature is "last" by ordering them by a chosen property. Doing that, it makes sense to use `Take(1)` in `Include`, for example to get the most recent one:

```cs
_context.Cities
    .Include(x=> x.Temperatures.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).Take(1));
```

Filtered/ordered `Include` is supported [as of EF core 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core/61147681#61147681).

Since you're already trying something along these lines I'm assuming you're using EFC 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by projecting the city and the last temperature to a new object, in a `Select` expression. The code snippet you included in your question is missing a few steps, so I'm going to take a guess at your data structures:

```
await _context.Cities.Select(city => new
{
    City = city,
    LastTemperature = city.Temperatures
                         .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateRecorded)
                         .FirstOrDefault(),
}).ToListAsync();
```