# How to implement searching with Include in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models in my project. first for Movie and second for Genre. There is a many-to-many relation between the two. So I created another model named MovieGenre. The problem is I don't know how to implement a search function in the controller for name of the Genre. To retrieve a movie with the specified genre name I mean.

Here is the three models

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    }

public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
    }

public class MovieGenre
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just create a List<Movie> prop in Genre model, no need for MovieGenre model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query has nothing with `Include` but how to implement filter

```cs
var result = ctx.Movie
    .Where(m => m.MovieGenres.Any(mg => mg.Genre.Name == genreName))
    .ToList();
```

If you are using EF Core 5+, consider to simplify your model. Intermediate entity can be omitted/hidden, check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many):

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var result = ctx.Movie
    .Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g.Name == genreName))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: FYI: EF core support many-to-many relations w/o intermediate entity since version 5.0.

Comment: So it doesn't need to create a separate join table! Thanks Man!

Comment: @ahamadzooghi, actually join table will be created automatically, so you do not need to do that by yourself.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv So what about Fluent API? Does it mean we don't need to write any code on Fluent API anymore? Is it all automated on EF CORE 5+?