# AutoMapper ProjectTo from a model with child list entity

Tags: automapper, automapper-11

Is this possible in AutoMapper?

1. Select list of type X and filter child entity of type Y (return single value of Y)
2. ProjectTo to a flat DTO contains props from X and Y.

If it is not, then what is the best way to populate the DTO in this scenario, the tables are just for example, in the real scenario the tables have a lot of columns and I want to avoid reading the whole row just to get one or two props.

Below is a quick console App code in .Net 5.0

**Project.csproj**

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

**Console App Testing Code**

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using AutoMapper;
    using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace MappingTest
    {
        public class Parent
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string ParentName { get; set; }
            public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
        }
    
        public class Child
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string ChildName { get; set; }
            public Parent Parent { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class ParentDto
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string ParentName { get; set; }
            public string ChildName { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class DataContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDb");
            }
        }
    
        internal class Program
        {
            public static void Seed(DataContext context)
            {
                context.Parents.Add(new Parent
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ParentName = "John",
                    Children = new List<Child>()
                        {
                            new Child { Id = 1, ChildName = "Peter", Age = 10 },
                            new Child { Id = 2, ChildName = "Smith", Age = 20 }
                        }
                });
    
                context.Parents.Add(new Parent
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    ParentName = "Micheal",
                    Children = new List<Child>()
                        {
                            new Child { Id = 3, ChildName = "Wale", Age = 10 },
                            new Child { Id = 4, ChildName = "Robert", Age = 25 }
                        }
                });
    
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<Child, ParentDto>();
                });
    
                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    
    
                using (var context = new DataContext())
                {
                    Seed(context);
    
                    var parent = context.Parents
                        // Filter children and get only the 10 years old (Peter and Wale)
                        // Project to the Dto and have the ChildName mapped to the Dto
                        // Note: Parent should have only one 10 years old child
                        .ProjectTo<ParentDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                        .ToList();
    
                    foreach(var p in parent)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}",p.Id, p.ParentName, p.ChildName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Could not find a similar scenario with a solution

**Update #1**

I'm really considering Dapper No Mapper, @Prolog your answer helped a lot, I managed to solve it correctly by using the other way around

```cs
    var config = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>();
    
                    cfg.CreateMap<Child, ParentDto>()
                        .IncludeMembers(e => e.Parent);
                });
```

And then ProjectTo like this

```cs
    var parents = context.Parents
                        .SelectMany(e => e.Children.Where(a => a.Age == 10))
                        .ProjectTo<ParentDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                        .ToList();
```

But the generated SQL is funny

```sql
    SELECT [t].[ChildName], [t].[Id], [p0].[ParentName]
    FROM [Parents] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[ChildName], [c].[ParentId]
        FROM [Children] AS [c]
        WHERE [c].[Age] = 10
    ) AS [t] ON [p].[Id] = [t].[ParentId]
    LEFT JOIN [Parents] AS [p0] ON [t].[ParentId] = [p0].[Id]
```

Where the required SQL is very simple

```sql
SELECT p.Id, 
       p.ParentName, 
       c.ChildName
FROM dbo.Parents p
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Children c ON p.Id = c.Id
-- or INNER JOIN
WHERE c.Age = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IncludeMembers()` to tell AutoMapper to try to fill properties of `ParentDto` will values from `Child` after it is done with mapping from `Parent`. Read more about this feature in [AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers).

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>()
        .IncludeMembers(src => src.Children.First());
    cfg.CreateMap<Child, ParentDto>();
});
```

Also, don't test your database-oriented projections with an In-Memory database, as it will hide all kind of query execution errors until you switch to a real database.

So if you want to filter out only to parents with a child that's 10 years old:

```cs
var parents = context.Parents
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(x => x.Age == 10))
    .ProjectTo<ParentDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToList();
```

with Microsoft SQL-Server, such query will be produced:

```sql
SELECT [p].[id],
       [p].[parentname],
       (SELECT TOP(1) [c0].[childname]
        FROM   [children] AS [c0]
        WHERE  [p].[id] = [c0].[parentid]) AS [ChildName]
FROM   [parents] AS [p]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   [children] AS [c]
               WHERE  ( [p].[id] = [c].[parentid] )
                      AND ( [c].[age] = 10 ))
```

Comment: your answer is highly appreciated, though it is not working, first it would fetch the first record from the child entity regardless of the filter try it with order switched like  new Child { Id = 3, ChildName = "Wale", Age = 25 },
                        new Child { Id = 4, ChildName = "Robert", Age = 10 } and you will get the wrong result the .First() is triggered in the mapping before the actual filter on the query body. the other issue is this code will generate N + 1 problem which really not effecient

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I checked with suggested different data and it did what you described, it ignored the filter. I shall remove my answer. And if I manage to come up with a valid solution, I'll post another. Now I can see that what you are really after is a form of [filtered include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core). You can still try to use AutoMapper for it, but filters are usully dynamic while mapping is usually constant. Consider if AutoMapper is the right tool for the job.

Comment: You can add the filter in the `IncludeMembers` expression. And about performance, n+1 means n queries, and there is only one here. I'm not sure how this could be more efficient, but you can always write the query by hand and rewrite with `ProjectTo`. But this looks pretty good to me :)

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu, is the SELECT TOP(1) inside the first select is not an N+1? and is it recommended to shift the business logic to the mapper?

Comment: No, that's a correlated subquery. There is no business logic here.