# Why doesn't EF Core filtered include work as expected when selecting into a new object?

Tags: entity-framework

When I use a filtered `Include`

```
var query = _dbContext.Plants
.Include(x => x.Units.Where(u => u.IsActive))
.Select(x => new PlantGridDTO
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Units = x.Units
});
```

The sql created does not include my filter at all

```
SELECT p.PLANTID, p.NAME, u.UNITID, u.INSERTEDBYID, u.INSERTEDDATE, u.ISACTIVE, u.MODIFIEDBYID, u.MODIFIEDDATE, u.NAME NAME1, u.PLANTID PLANTID1, u.UNITSUBTYPEID
FROM SPORTDB.PLANT p
LEFT JOIN SPORTDB.UNIT u ON p.PLANTID = u.PLANTID
ORDER BY p.PLANTID
```

But when I move the filter into the select, the sql looks correct.

```
var query = _dbContext.Plants
.Include(x => x.Units)
.Select(x => new PlantGridDTO
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Units = x.Units.Where(u => u.IsActive)
});

SELECT p.PLANTID, p.NAME, t.UNITID, t.INSERTEDBYID, t.INSERTEDDATE, t.ISACTIVE, t.MODIFIEDBYID, t.MODIFIEDDATE, t.NAME NAME1, t.PLANTID PLANTID1, t.UNITSUBTYPEID
FROM SPORTDB.PLANT p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.UNITID, u.INSERTEDBYID, u.INSERTEDDATE, u.ISACTIVE, u.MODIFIEDBYID, u.MODIFIEDDATE, u.NAME, u.PLANTID, u.UNITSUBTYPEID
    FROM SPORTDB.UNIT u
    WHERE u.ISACTIVE = 1
) t ON p.PLANTID = t.PLANTID
ORDER BY p.PLANTID
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What version are you using? It was only added in EF Core 5.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include

Comment: We're running EF6

Comment: I can't find any official documentation but this SO answer says the behaviour you're seeing is expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/8607541

Comment: Are you using EF6 or EF Core 6?

Comment: ...Both I think

Comment: I eventually stumbled onto this answer that explains how filtered `Include` works with Entity Framework core https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/251614