# Entity Framework linq get multiple nested entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I wrote a linq query to fetch multiple nested entities. I need to get all the questions except the ones that are deleted and the ones with a `parentId`. This is where it's going wrong. All the results are fine, except the result set still contains questions where the parent id is not null. What am I doing wrong?

I think it might has to do with the `filterquestions`, these are also questions self referring to another question. I need these questions only in the list of `filterquestions` and not in both.

```
public async Task<QuestionList?> GetAsyncQuestionTree(Guid id)
{
    var tree = await _dbContext.QuestionLists
        .Where(list => list.Id == id)
        .Include(list => list.Modules)!
            .ThenInclude(module => module.Questions!.Where(m => m.isDeleted == false && m.ParentId == null))!
                .ThenInclude(question => question.AnswerOptions)
        .Include(list => list.Modules)!
            .ThenInclude(module => module.Questions!.Where(m => m.isDeleted == false && m.ParentId == null))!
            .ThenInclude(question => question.FilterQuestions)
                .ThenInclude(question => question.AnswerOptions)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return tree;
}
```

Comment: [`Include` does not filter the query, only included collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, although if I just do a single include it does work. I'll check the link you send to find out how I could make this work

Comment: BTW what I said is the Incudes don't filter `_dbContext.QuestionLists`, but that wasn't relevant, actually. But if questions are interrelated somehow, yes then other questions may enter the result, but that's hard to judge w/o seeing the classes.