# AutoMapper bringing data out of nowhere after Entity Framework Query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, orm, automapper

I'm using *.NET Core 7* and *Entity Framework Core 7.0.13* and *AutoMapper 12.0.3* and I have the following query:

```
var test = _context.Set<T>
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(m => m.MachineOperations!
        .Where(m =>
            m.InsertedAt.Date <= endDate.Date &&
            m.EndTime <= endDate.TimeOfDay &&
            m.InsertedAt.Date >= startDate.Date &&
            m.StartTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay))
    .ThenInclude(m => m.EggQuantities)
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay);

var test2 = _mapper.ProjectTo<MachineScheduleDataDto>(test);
```

My problem is that the `.Where` clause is not being applied. After some tries, I realized that if I add a `.ToList()` at the end of the query and after I convert it using `.AsQueryable()` to pass as an argument to the mapper, the `.Where` clause works fine. Why does it happen? I can't use `.ToList()` because it selects all the properties of the classes that I am querying.

After many tries, I realized that my query was ok, my problem is inside of the .ProjectTo().
For example, if I pass some argumentes that shouldn't return any *MachineOperation*, the query doesn't actually return anything, which is ok, but when the result of the query pass through the `.ProjectTo`, it magically finds some records and brings it to me. It really doesn't make any sense to me.

Result of the query:
[image]

Result of the .ProjectTo():
[image]

MachineScheduleDataDto class:

```
public record MachineScheduleDataDto
{
    public required ICollection<MachineOperationDto> MachineOperationsDto { get; set; }
}

public record MachineOperationDto
{
    public int MachineOperationId { get; set; }
    public EMachineStatus MachineStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual required MachineScheduleDataDto MachineScheduleDto { get; set; }
}
```

My Mappers:

```
CreateMap<MachineSchedule, MachineScheduleDataDto>()
    .ForMember(p => p.MachineOperationsDto, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.MachineOperations));

CreateMap<MachineOperation, MachineOperationDto>()
   .ForMember(p => p.MachineScheduleDto, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.MachineSchedule));
```

Comment: Just FYI you shouldn't need `Include`'s with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: But how would I filter an included entity so?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core/61147681#61147681) to understand everything about `Include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because using `ProjectTo` is equivalent to applying custom `Select` to query in EF Core (i.e. custom projection), which results in `Include`'s being ignored (including the filter). You can try to move the filtering logic into the mapping expression (maybe by using an intermediate type for this, according to the [AutoMapper docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems) it should work) or apply mapping after materialization (as your working attempt does) but it can lead to fetching extra data.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you, updated answer with the link!