# How to use .Select() to map an object with list properties of different types in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, mapper

I am using *.NET 7* and I have an Entity Framework Query that needs to be mapped to this DTO:

```
public record MachineScheduleDataDto
{
   public int MachineScheduleId { get; set; }
   public required ICollection<MachineOperationDto> MachineOperationsDto { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to map the `MachineOperationsDto` propety, once it is an ICollection and have a type different of the class that will mapped it.

The EF query:

```
var test = _typedContext
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(m => m.MachineOperations!
        .Where(m =>
            m.InsertedAt.Date <= endDate.Date &&
            m.EndTime <= endDate.TimeOfDay &&
            m.InsertedAt.Date >= startDate.Date &&
            m.StartTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay))
    .ThenInclude(m => m.EggQuantities)
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay)
    .OrderBy(m => m.MachineScheduleId)
    .Select(m => new MachineScheduleDataDto
    {
        MachineScheduleId = m.MachineScheduleId,
        MachineOperationsDto = // Error because m.MachineOperation has the type "MachineOperation" and the MachineOperationsDto has the type "MachineOperationDto"
    });
```

The model that I'll use to make the map:

```
public class MachineOperation : BaseModel
{
    public int MachineOperationId { get; set; }
    public EMachineStatus MachineStatus { get; set; }
    public EDevStatus DevStatus { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

    #region Relationships

    public required virtual MachineSchedule MachineSchedule { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

The DTO:

```
public record MachineOperationDto
{
    public int MachineOperationId { get; set; }
    public EMachineStatus MachineStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual required MachineScheduleDataDto MachineScheduleDto { get; set; }
}
```

**PS: I CAN'T USE AUTOMAPPER BECAUSE OF THE FILTER INSIDE THE INCLUDE THAT IS IGNORED BY THE AUTOMAPPER, SEE [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77453187/automapper-bringing-data-out-of-nowhere-after-entity-framework-query)**

Comment: `MachineOperationsDto  =  new MachineOperationsDto  { ... }` but note that `Select` will have the same "problems" - it ignores `Include`'s, you need to move the filtering logic (from the include) to the `Select` statement.

Comment: Also note - you can use AutoMapper - check out the suggestion to move the filtering to the mapper (updated the previous answer with the links to doc - https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems)

Comment: * `MachineOperationsDto  = m.MachineOperation.Where(...).Select(x => new MachineOperationsDto  { ... })`

Comment: You can use Automapper but not `ProjectTo` method. Materialize query then apply Automapper.

Comment: No, I can't do this because if  I materialize the query, i'll search for all properties of my model. My query will be slower

Comment: @quirms setting up the filtering in the AutoMapper will not lead to "premature" materialization.

Answer (score 1):

Project everything via `Select`

```cs
var test = _typedContext
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay)
    .OrderBy(m => m.MachineScheduleId)
    .Select(m => new MachineScheduleDataDto
    {
        MachineScheduleId = m.MachineScheduleId,
        MachineOperationsDto = m.MachineOperations!
            .Where(mo =>
                mo.InsertedAt.Date <= endDate.Date &&
                mo.EndTime <= endDate.TimeOfDay &&
                mo.InsertedAt.Date >= startDate.Date &&
                mo.StartTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay)
            .Select(mo => new MachineOperationDto
            {
                ... // other properties
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, what this link should tell me if this query do not use AutoMapper? It is regular Eager Loading query.

Comment: It says how you do it with `ProjectTo`, you said you cannot use it :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, can you apply with `ProjectTo` filter based on parameters? It is case when `ProjectTo` is useless.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, you are right, missed that. Anyway moving business logic to the mapping is a bad idea.

Comment: That's not business logic, it's a query. That's a classic use case for AM, but of course you must be familiar with AM's abstractions to make sense of a `ProjectTo` query.