# EF Core .Includes() not returning related entity with Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have a Company and a Review class. I also have a CompanyResponse and ReviewResponse DTO classes with fewer properties that I want to send back to the client.

```cs
public class CompanyResponse {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundedDate { get; set; }
    public StatusType StatusType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyReviewResponse> CompanyReviews { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}


public class ReviewResponse {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Rating Rating { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my mappings at the moment are like this:

```
CreateMap<Company, CompanyResponse>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Review, ReviewResponse>().ReverseMap();
```

In my repository I have a method like this to get related entities.

```cs
     public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllIncludingAsync(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) {
            IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

At the moment If i just return the entities, I actually get the company with all of its reviews. But I want to exclude a lot of the fields that aren't needed.

I have a method in my service layer like this:

```cs
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyResponse>> GetCompanies(bool doIncludeCompanyReviews = false) {
        var companies = await _repository.GetAllIncludingAsync(c => c.Reviews);
        var mappedCompaniesResponse = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyResponse>>(companies);
        return mappedCompaniesResponse;
    }
```

But it does not return me the reviews, just the company. (The company is mapped to the CompanyResponse fields when using Postman.

Any tips on how to get this to work please?

**EDIT** ----------------------------------------------

Made some changes to retrieve all companies like this:

```cs
        var companies = _context.Company.ProjectTo<CompanyResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

and also added this Mapping profile

```cs
     CreateMap<Company, CompanyResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Reviews,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Reviews)).ReverseMap();
```

And it works now

Comment: Are the review included in `companies`?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In my actual Entity class, yes it is. I have a navigation property for Reviewws

Comment: I'm not sure if it's my Automapper Profile Mapping thats set up incorrectly to handle this?

Comment: But are the reviews being returned property by EF on line 1 of GetCompanies()?  IE is this an EF issue or an automapper issue?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes they are in the response. It works when I return the actual entity and not the DTOs to the client. In that case i actually get the list of reviews.

Comment: Just don't use mapper.Map, use ProjectTo and everything will be "included" automatically. And don't use a repository layer, for that matter.

Comment: Use `ProjectTo` and setup corresponding mapping. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453270/2501279)

Comment: @ServletException feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I did edit my post with a solution that worked for me @GuruStron. I'll add an answer now

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution thanks to everyone in the comments.

Made some changes to retrieve all companies like this:

```cs
var companies = _context.Company.ProjectTo<CompanyResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

and also added this Mapping profile

```cs
CreateMap<Company, CompanyResponse>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Reviews,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Reviews)).ReverseMap();
```

And it works now.

Additional filtering can be applied by appending .Where(Expression..) before the ProjectTo<> call

Comment: The `MapFrom` is useless.