# How to apply where clause on ICollection LINQ result?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have three class in my project:

```
public partial class Product
{
 public string? Title { get; set; }
 public string? UrlAddress { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
 public virtual Picture? Picture { get; set; }
 
}


public partial class ProductSize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Size Size { get; set; } = null!;
}


public partial class Size
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And try to get something result with this linq query:

```
var result =   _tebpooshContext.Products
   .Where(p => p.ProductCategoryId == 1
            && p.ProductTypeId == 2
   )
   
   .Include(p => p.Picture)
   .Include(p => p.ProductSizes)
   .ThenInclude(p => p.Size)
   
   .Select(p => new TileProductDto
   {
       Image = p.Picture.Url.Replace("SYSTEM_TYPE_SYNCSERVER", "URL"),
       Name = p.Name.Trim(),
       Price = p.Price.ToString(),
       ProductSizes = p.ProductSizes,
       ProdutId = p.Id.ToString(),


   })

   .Take(9).ToList();
```

Now try to write this where clause before `Take(9)` with this syntax:

```
.Where(p => p.ProductSizes.Where(p => p.Size.Name == "42"))
```

but get this error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TebWebApp.models.entities.ProductSize>' to 'bool'
```

Try to fix that error with this way :

`.Where(p => p.ProductSizes.Any(p => p.Size.Name == "42"))`

But that where clause return all product size and size "42" dont effect on where clause.

How can i apply my where clause before `Take(9)` ?

Comment: What do you want to do in the first place? This has nothing to do with `Take` or collections. In fact, the first expression makes little sense. WHERE expects a condition that's true for the rows you want to include, not a list of values. The second will limit products to those that have a ProductSize.Name=="42". If all products have a 42, all will be returned. If you don't want that either, what *do* you want?

Comment: Are you trying to load only the 42 product size perhaps? Try `.Include(p => p.ProductSizes.Where(p=>p.Name=="42"))`. `Include(..Where)` will only load the related objects that match the expression

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to Fetch Product.Size == "42" in First Take(9)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Write .ThenInclude(p => p.Size.Name == "42") but get this error :The expression '(p.Size.Name == "42")' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types

Comment: That's not what I wrote at all. Use `.Include(p => p.ProductSizes.Where(p=>p.Size.Name=="42"))` instead of `.Include(p => p.ProductSizes)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Write this ```.Include(p => p.ProductSizes.Where(p=>p.Size.Name=="42"))``` and get all size but i want get just ```size == "42"```

Comment: @GertArnold Which part of my code should I add? ```ProductSizes = p.ProductSizes```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Include`s are ignored when the query ends in a projection (i.e. a `Select(x => new ...)` statement. They should be removed (code should not contain redundancies).

What you want can be implemented by adding a `Where` in the projection:

```cs
var result = _tebpooshContext.Products
   .Where(p => p.ProductCategoryId == 1
            && p.ProductTypeId == 2)
   .Select(p => new TileProductDto
   {
       Image = p.Picture.Url.Replace("SYSTEM_TYPE_SYNCSERVER", "URL"),
       Name = p.Name.Trim(),
       Price = p.Price.ToString(),
       ProductSizes = p.ProductSizes.Where(p => p.Size.Name == "42"), // here
       ProdutId = p.Id.ToString(),
   })
   .Take(9).ToList();
```

As for the filter...

```cs
_tebpooshContext.Products.Where(p => p.ProductSizes.Any(p => p.Size.Name == "42"))
```

That only filters the products in the end result, but when you only have `ProductSizes = p.ProductSizes` in the projection, you still get all `ProductSizes` of these products. This is similar to the difference between [Filtered Include vs filtering the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716).