# C# Linq filter and remove record on child collection while returning parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
Parent                   Child
-------------            -----
int id;                  int id;
string name;             string name;
List<Child> children;    bool isDeleted;
```

I am using EF and I want to get the parent child collection by parent id where the child is not deleted.

I tried the following:

```
var parentRepo = repoFactory.Get<ParentRepo>();
var parent = parentRepo.where(x => x.id == parentId && x.children.All(y => !y.isDeleted));
```

but that did not work.  I also tried the following and worked:

```
var parentRepo = repoFactory.Get<ParentRepo>();
var parent = parentRepo.where(x => x.id == parentId);
             .Select(x => new { id = x.id, name = x.name, children = x.children.Where(y=> !y.isDeleted).ToList() }).ToList()
             .Select(y => new Parent { id = y.id, name = y.name, children = y.children }).ToList();
```

But the class that I am working with is quite big and I am not sure if it is good practice to populate each property like that and I might be missing some in the future if I were to add new property.

Is there another to filter out the inner collection while keeping the outer(parent) one?  Thnaks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects

Comment: What do you mean "did not work". What happens, and how is it different from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the parent child collection by parent id where the child
>   is not deleted.

This is a bit unclear, but I assume this means that you want the collection of those `Parents` that have at least one `Child` who is not deleted, together will all their non-deleted children.

It could also mean that you only want `Parents` that have no deleted `Children`. In that case the query will be similar.

If you have your entity framework [one-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) modeled according to the rules, this is easy.

```
class Parent
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     // a Parent has zero or more Children:
     public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
     ...
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // a Child belongs to exactly one Parent, via foreign key ParentId:
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Normally this would have been enough to inform entity framework that you modeled a one-to-many relation ship between `Parent` and `Children`. Because of the non-standard pluralization of `Child` into `Children` some fluent API or attributes might be needed, but that is out of the scope of this question.

By the way, did you notice I changed your List to an ICollection? I haven't tested it, but I'm quite certain that entity framework doesn't work correctly with Lists. I wonder what happens if you query the following:

```
Child thirdChild = Parent.children[3];
```

Once you have modeled your one-to-many correctly, your query will be simple:

```
// all parents that have at least one child that is not deleted:
var allParentsWithNonDeletedChildren = myDbContext.Parents
    .Select(parent => new
    {    // take only the Parent properties you will use:
         Id = parent.Id,
         Name = parent.Name,

         // take only the non-deleted children:
         Children = parent.Children.Where(child => !child.IsDelected),
    })
    // keep only those parents that have any non-deleted Children:
    .Where(parent => parent.Children.Any());
```

In words:

from every parent in the collection of Parents, create one object of [anonymous type](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx) with the parent's Id and Name, and a collection of non-deleted Children. From the resulting collection take only those object that have a children collection with at least one child.