# Entity FrameWork Filter Navigation Properties Does Not Work

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I realised I need to filter out some entities from the navigation property in EF. I found Microsoft's own page on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter

I have copied their code into vb.net as closely as I can for my entities. I changed the filter after it did not work so that it should filter out everything (id = -99). This still did not work. It gets the Invoice but does not filter any of the related Invoice details.

```
Dim Inv = MyBase.Context.Invoices.Include(Function(x) x.InvoiceDetails).Where(Function(x) x.id = id).FirstOrDefault

MyBase.Context.Entry(Inv).Collection(Function(x) x.InvoiceDetails).Query().Where(Function(d) d.id = -99).Load()

Dim cc = Inv.InvoiceDetails.Count

If cc > 1 Then

Debug.Write(cc)''This should not run as all should be filtered out but it does

End If
```

Any ideas? My code seems to match thiers very closely. I have tried this with and without the ".include".

Comment: So you don't want any InvoiceDetails? Why not just use Find on the invoice as they do in the example? If you then want a subset of InvoiceDetails, apply the query on the collection.

Comment: @NDC you can't filter include statement with where. In the explicit filter they are just including the select statement

Answer (score 0):

> **Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related
>   entities.**

Entity framework team are working on it. Its a upcoming feature

[Request this feature](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method)

please see the 
[Explicit filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter)

[LINQ Query - how sort and filter on eager fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324931/linq-query-how-sort-and-filter-on-eager-fetch/5325160#5325160)