# Filtering query by child entity element

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used entity framework with my example. I wanted to filter child entity but I am getting exception 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.'

```
public List<Notification> GetNotificationBySentDate(DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime == null)
        {
            return
                _dbContext.Notifications.Include(x => x.Attachments.Select(a=>a.Clean==true))
                    .Where(x => 
                        x.Sent == null && 
                        x.FaultCount <= _appSettingsHelper.NotificationsFaultCountLimit &&
                        DbFunctions.AddSeconds(x.CreatedDate, x.DelaySeconds) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    .OrderBy(a => DbFunctions.AddSeconds(a.CreatedDate, a.DelaySeconds))
                    .Take(_appSettingsHelper.NotificationsBySentStateSelectTop).ToList();
        }
        return _dbContext.Notifications.Include(x => x.Attachments).Where(x => x.Sent >= dateTime)
            .OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDate)
            .Take(_appSettingsHelper.NotificationsBySentStateSelectTop).ToList();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589645/entity-framework-filter-navigation-properties-does-not-work/31591929#31591929

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with `Select` statement under the `Include`. You can try to remove it and add an additional clause to `Where`, something like `&& x.Attachements.Clean == true`. Thus your code will be

```
               _dbContext.Notifications.Include(x => x.Attachments)
                .Where(x => 
                    x.Sent == null && 
                    x.FaultCount <= _appSettingsHelper.NotificationsFaultCountLimit &&
                    DbFunctions.AddSeconds(x.CreatedDate, x.DelaySeconds) < DateTime.UtcNow &&
                    x.Attachments.Clean == true)
                .OrderBy(a => DbFunctions.AddSeconds(a.CreatedDate, a.DelaySeconds))
                .Take(_appSettingsHelper.NotificationsBySentStateSelectTop).ToList();
```

Comment: That will give me notifications only when attachments are clean. My requirement is I need all notifications if there are any attachments to the notifications then get only ones that are clean