# Filter in child list LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have list function contain list language in side

[image] 
I want to filter that list Language with condition `CulNo = "en"`.

Here is my code:

```
var functionLang = 
    functionVm.Where(x => x.Language.Any(y => y.LanguageCountry.CulNo == cul));
```

But it still returns all languages. How can I filter with list function have list language with my condition?

Comment: You are saying to get any object where **one** of its languages is English. If that object has two languages (English **and** Mandarin) then will return both. That is what `Any` does.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to achieve? You want a list of objects that (what)?

Comment: i want to list function have only language i pass , it mean list language only have one object.

Comment: With `all` you get only languages where there is only "EN":`var functionLang = 
    functionVm.Where(x => x.Language.All(y => y.LanguageCountry.CulNo == cul));`

Comment: @AntonioCampagnaro if change to all it get nothing in list @@

Comment: Can you try `var functionLang = functionVm.Where(x => x.Language.All(y => y.LanguageCountry.CulNo.ToLower() == cul.ToLower()));`

Comment: Are you sure that exists any function with only one language? Can you provide us your data or add a simple code that works in a Console application?

Comment: @viveknuna my parameter pass all also lower case and get nothing in list

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a language which has a property, FunctionViewModel, link to its parent (type: FunctionViewModel)

```
var functionLang = language.Include(l=>l.FunctionViewModel)
.Where(l=>l.LanguageCountry.CulNo == cul)
.Select(l=>l.FunctionViewModel)
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

And it will only includes FunctionViewModels which have and only have English in Language property.

There's no Include filter support yet for EF core

Comment: Historically this was not supported by EF, This feature is still open in EF core too.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try anonymous projection to filter**

```
var langs = language
           .Select(g=> new 
           {
             g =  g.Language.where(y => y.LanguageCountry.CulNo == cul)
           }).ToList();
```

[Filter child entities reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720573/linq-to-entities-how-to-filter-on-child-entities/4724297#4724297)