# Filtering Related Entites with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

According to this StackOverflow answer:

[Linq to Entities - how to filter on child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720573/linq-to-entities-how-to-filter-on-child-entities/4724297#4724297)

you should be able to filter down the list of related entities in Entity Framework by utilizing a projection, like I've done here:

```
Company company = _context.Company
.Where(g => g.CompanyId == id)
.Select(comp => new
{
    group = comp,
    operators = comp.Operator,
    formFamilies = comp.FormFamily.Where(ff => ff.IsActive ?? false)
}).AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.group).FirstOrDefault();
```

To give a quick overview of what I'm trying to obtain here, I'm trying to get a list of all of the active form families associated with this company object, however, whenever I restrict the results in any way, the result set is empty.

- If the line were `formFamilies = comp.FormFamily` then it returns two results, one active one inactive
- If the line is `formFamilies = comp.FormFamily.Where(ff => true)` then it returns nothing
- If the line is `formFamilies = comp.FormFamily.OrderBy(ff => ff.FormFamilyId)` then it returns nothing.

Any sort of modification that I do to `comp.FormFamily` means the result set returns nothing, I've dug through the deepest sections of SA to try to find a solution, and tried every solution I've found, but nothing seems to cause this list to return anything.

Comment: could u plz add your `Company` and `FormFamily` entity to your question?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Company and FormFamily entities has one to many relationship I would suggest to use a join statement.Something like this should give you what you are looking for.

```
  var company =  from c in _context.Company
                           join f in _context.FormFamily
                           on c.Id equals f.CompanyId   
                           where c.Id == id
                           select new Company()
                           {
                               Id = c.Id,
                               operators = c.Operator.ToList(),
                               formFamilies = c.FormFamily.Where(x=>x.IsActive == 
                                               false).ToList()
                           } .FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I eventually solved the issue by using populating the list with a second query by using:
`_context.Entry(company)
 .Collection(ff => ff.FormFamily).Query().Where(ff => ff.IsActive ?? false)
 .Load();`
But that did it in two queries.
Out of curiosity, is there any way that you know to convert it to linq-to-entities? I mainly use that and would prefer not to mix syntax.

Comment: Join syntax gets a bit weird in method form. Something like this might help you
          `var company = _context.Company.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == Id).Join(_dbContext.FormFamily,x => x.Id, c => c.CompanyId                                                    , (x, c) => x).Select(x => new Company() {                                                          Id =x.Id,formFamilies = c.FormFamily.Where(x=>x.IsActive ==                                             false).ToList(),    }); `

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what is your query is supposed to do. But it seems to me that you cannot just call Select method on another Select result method.

Anyway, you could simply use `Include` methods instead of projecting.

```
var company = _context.Company
    .Where(c => c.Id == id)
    .Include(c => c.FormFamily).Where(ff => ff.IsActive ?? false)
    .ToList();
```

Did not test it. To prove it works or not be sure put an entity model in the question. Then I may produce more accurate answer.

Comment: That won't work, when you call where on an include you will get an exception.